# How can I parse a list of RSS feeds one at a time?

Tags: ios, parsing, rss

I'm essentially saving the items from RSS feeds into an array and then placing that array into another one to contain them all. For instance, I'm working on saving a bunch of educational videos by Chapter (each chapter has an RSS feed), so I'm parsing them using MWFeedParser all at once using this logic:

```
for (NSString *url in videosArray) {    
        NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
        feedParser.delegate = self;
        feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull;
        feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
        [feedParser parse];
        }
```

While this does the job, if the Chapter 3 RSS feed finishes parsing before Chapter 2, the content of Chapter 3 is saved in Chapter 2's spot. While this may sound like an unnecessarily complicated explanation, my request is simply this:

Is there any way to parse one feed at a time from a list of feeds and not continue until a feed is fully parsed it's contents are inserted into the array?

If it helps, here are 4 delegate methods that may be useful:

```
- (void)feedParserDidStart:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
NSLog(@"Started Parsing: %@", parser.url);
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedInfo:(MWFeedInfo *)info {
NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Info: “%@”", info.title);
self.title = info.title;
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);
if (item) [parsedItems addObject:item];
}

- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
NSLog(@"Finished Parsing%@", (parser.stopped ? @" (Stopped)" : @""));
[courseBeingBuilt.mediaCollection addObject:parsedItems]; // Place chapter contents into Course's Chapter w/contents array
parsedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create new array for new chapter
}
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you could keep track of the index within `videosArray` in a variable (say, `NSUInteger currentIndex`) and use that in the `feedParserDidFinish:` method to start parsing the next feed.

Write the following method:

```
- (void) parseNextVideo
{
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[videosArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex++]];
    feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    feedParser.delegate = self;
    feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull;
    feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
    [feedParser parse];
}
```

Instead of your `for` loop, just:

```
currentIndex = 0;
[self parseNextVideo];
```

And then in `feedParserDidFinish:`:

```
NSLog(@"Finished Parsing%@", (parser.stopped ? @" (Stopped)" : @""));
[courseBeingBuilt.mediaCollection addObject:parsedItems]; // Place chapter contents into Course's Chapter w/contents array
parsedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create new array for new chapter
if (currentIndex < videosArray.count) {
    [self parseNextVideo];
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I've been doing this thing in such long periods that I couldn't even think anymore! Thanks a ton for your help buddy!

Comment: Does NSOperation help in loading multiple NSURL?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it sounds much broader than should be answered in a comment thread. You should [search StackOverflow and maybe ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). `NSOperation` can be used to perform just about any task. Inserted into an `NSOperationQueue`, those tasks can be performed one at a time, or multiple at a  time, until the queue is empty. So you could use an `NSOperationQueue` to load multiple urls.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting all those parsers loose at once, make your delegate object a little smarter: have it keep a mutable array of the feed URLs that have not yet been parsed. When you get a call to `feedParserDidFinish:`, create the next parser and remove its URL from the list. If there are no feeds left in the array, you're done.

You should also implement the delegate method that indicates failure, since you might encounter an unrecoverable error for a single feed (feed doesn't exist at URL), a transient error affecting all network operations (network connection dropped), or some other undesirable situation. You'll want to handle each of these cases appropriately.